# PowerBI Embedded report hangs on loading when rendered by Javascript API

Tags: javascript, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to embed a PowerBI report into my web app, that is running locally in my dev server, with the Javascript API. I know everything is working since I succesfully rendered the desired report in their [Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#), so it can't be a problem with the Embedded Server or Azure. In my console window there are multiple warnings and errors of external resources blocked by the same origin policy, and an `uncaught exception: [object Object]` error probably related to the PBI Javascript API that i can't decipher. The report just loads forever, displaying the animated PowerBI logo. Is anybody else experiencing this issue while trying to embed a report locally? Here's the code responsible for rendering:

```
var embedContainer = $("#container");
var models = window.['powerbi-client'].models;

    var config= {
        type: 'report',
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
        accessToken: ginormous embed token,
        embedUrl: https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=ommited_for_privacy&groupId=ommited_for_privacy,
        id: the_report_id,
        permissions: models.Permissions.All,
        settings: {
                filterPaneEnabled: true,
                navContentPaneEnabled: true
        }
    };

    // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
    var report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer.get(0), config);

    // Report.off removes a given event handler if it exists.
    report.off("loaded");

    // Report.on will add an event handler which prints to Log window.
    report.on("loaded", function() {
        Log.logText("Loaded");
    });

    report.on("error", function(event) {
        Log.log(event.detail);

        report.off("error");
    });

    report.off("saved");
    report.on("saved", function(event) {
        Log.log(event.detail);
        if(event.detail.saveAs) {
                Log.logText('In order to interact with the new report, create a new token and load the new report');
        }
    });
```

Here are all the console errors:

```
uncaught exception: [object Object]

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost:3000/temp/scripts/App.js

Source Map URL: powerbi.js.map
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.5314.162/scripts/ai.0.js

Source Map URL: ai.0.js.map
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.5314.162/scripts/reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js

Source Map URL: interact.min.js.map
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad guys.

The problem is that Firefox did not show the reason of the exception, but Chrome did. I should've tested in another browser before asking. With the exception text, I could track the problem to a typo in the `tokenType` parameter and it worked just fine.